# Why does toStaticHTML remove data-* attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, winjs

My application dynamically builds HTML content as a string and when finished the content is being attached to the DOM. In WinJS however this throws exceptions once I try to attach the string to the DOM. In order to work around these exceptions I have to sanitize the HTML by running it through toStaticHTML, which is globally defined in WinJS as well as in Internet Explorer. The issue that I am having is that there are quite a lot of use of data-* html5 attributes. Once I run those through toStaticHTML they are being stripped. Why does toStaticHTML remove data-* attributes? What is the real security concern with them?

Note that I cannot wrap the DOM insertion in MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction because I am using jQuery and I am not allowed to modify the jQuery code.

```
var html = "<ul><li data-role='list-node'>My list node</li></ul>";
$('#container').html(toStaticHTML(html));
```

Produces:

```
<ul>
    <li>My list node</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `$('#container').html(html)` does not work? `html` is a string anyway...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because of security concerns about inserting random bits of HTML into the document, and potentially allowing unsafe code to execute inside a protected context (your app, with full access to the WinRT, and users documents).

`toStaticHtml` is intended to remain 'secure' in the case of evolving HTML/web patterns so it is a *whitelist* rather than a *blacklist*.

Given your challenge that you have here I see the following options:

- wrap the call to jquery in `msExecUnsafeLocalFunction` (see below). This means for the life of that call, all Dom insertions will be fine. This doesn't require a change to jquery, just your code.
- Completely rewrite any of the DOM calls that Jquery is using under the covers to call with `msExecUnsafeLocalFunction`
- Change the security context of your application to the web context rather than the local context. This, of course will lose you access to WinRT directly. You'll have to operate through some other mechanism (messaging between I frames or similar)
- Use `WinJS.Binding.Template` to render your content rather than Jquery. This clones the nodes rather than stringifying the HTML
- write your own node cloner
- set the attribute with `setAttribute` after the safe node is inserted.

Example usage of msExecUnsafeLocalFunction:

```
MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction(function() {
    $('#container').html(html);
});
```

Comment: I believe I tried wrapping my calls in MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction however I was still getting the exceptions. I will have to confirm this on Monday.

Comment: If the JQuery work is "Deferred" e.g. execution is yielded to the browser before it's actually set, then that may explain that. Looking at the code, that doesn't seem to happen. Updated to add another option too.

Comment: Actually jQuery should be using it's Deferred in this case. In fact there are cases where I am getting an error only if I use an MS Promise and if I don't then I'm not getting any errors, but a warning instead. I will update with further findings tomorrow.

Comment: I have updated my post above. Perhaps changing all implementation to use attr (setAttribute) would suffice, however if it's possible to not do this, because of the size of the code that I need to modify, it would be even better.

Comment: Your edit is not calling the function inside. Your calling the JSQuery function, and passing the result to the msExecUnsafeLocalFunction. Let me add an example.

Comment: I will try that tomorrow morning and will give you feedback on whether it works.

Answer (score 3):

The `data-role`-attribute is not listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465388.aspx

It's an unknown attribute and will be removed.

Comment: I still don't see a reason why all data-win-* attributes are allowed while other data-* are not. What is the security concern with the rest?

Comment: Well, I suppose *Standards information: There are no standards that apply here.* @ http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh466094.aspx gives a clue.

Comment: @Konstantin Dinev: Not "all" data-win-*-attributes at allowed, only the listed.

Comment: In this case my question can be reworded into "Why do I get an exception in WinJS when I try to attach html string to the DOM which contains data-* attributes, because by specification they should not be a security concern?": http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/global-attributes.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes

Comment: The w3c-specification is meaningless here.

Answer (score 0):

As mention in the docs `data` is not allowed: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465388.aspx

Comment: If referring to data-attribute I can confirm that these are allowed to be dynamically inserted with no extra measures taken.