# Using AppendTo/jquery-win8 in Win8 apps

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, windows-8, angularjs, winjs

I am tempting to look at the [ToDoMVC](https://github.com/addyosmani/todomvc) samples and have tried porting them to a Win8 JS app by just copying and pasting the code but also having the relevant WinJS libs referenced.

Due to MS security principals around InnerHTML etc I have referenced [jQuery-Win8](https://github.com/appendto/jquery-win8) which attempts to get around the issue however in the Angular and Backbone examples when I run the app I get an exception on appendChild

I've read in some places you should be able to continue running the app but if I do press Continue on the exception the app shuts down anyway.

Can anyone point me in the right direction to get this running?

Thanks

**UPDATE:** Here's a screenshot of the exception in VS [image]

Comment: Can you post more info on the exception you get mate

Comment: @Jon refer to this thread, it has a lot of relevant information for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234931/why-does-tostatichtml-remove-data-attributes

Comment: The exception says it is on line 22 of jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.min.js. The problem is the whole minified library is on line 22. Can you switch to the non-minified library jquery-1.8.2-win8-1.0.js and re-post the exception screenshot?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

appendTo's version removes errors that occur when running jQuery at load time. You still may have code that violates the security model Microsoft put in place. Microsoft is trying to make you aware that there is a risk adding un-sanitized markup to your page.

If you are confident that is not the case you can try setting `jQuery.isUnsafe` to `true` after the appendTo library is included. That should wrap all possible unsafe calls with `MSApp.execUnsafeLocalFunction` so that Microsoft doesn't complain.

Note: This flag is turned off by default