# toStaticHTML method removed name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, windows-8

I am developing a windows 8 app using javascript. I am trying to fetch dynamic content from server but I cant use dynamic content directly so I am using `toStaticHTML(result)` for getting result.

But My dynamic content includes

```
Male <input type="radio" name="sex" value="1"/> Female<input type="radio" name="sex" value="0"/>
```

But **name** attribute is not accepted in **toStaticHTML** method. What can i do to solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: Can you wrap your `result` in `MSApp.execUnsafeLocaLFunction()` as described [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234931/why-does-tostatichtml-remove-data-attributes#answer-12237833)?

Comment: @J.Wells Thanks a lot J.Wells. After struggling hours this solved my problem. Again Thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap your `result` in `MSApp.execUnsafeLocaLFunction()` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12234931/why-does-tostatichtml-remove-data-attributes#answer-12237833).